# When I transfer files between servers on my desktop is my computer an intermediary?

Tags: file-transfer

For example, on a Windows based system I have two windows explorer programs opened and in each explorer window I am viewing the contents of two server's files.

Now, if I were to transfer files between both servers by dragging files across my desktop from one into another are those files going directly to each other or is my PC being used as an intermediary and thereby slowing the transfer speed?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you are using Windows Explorer on desktop A to transfer files from server B to server C, then yes the files are traveling from B to A to C.

Generally, whatever machine is issuing the commands is doing the "work."  While there is nothing inherently wrong with doing the copy this way, there are some disadvantages.  For example, lets say you had a virus scanner installed on every machine.  Every time a file is accessed and written, the virus scanner will inspect the file.  You are adding more work to the entire process and slowing things down.

The easiest way to bypass this method is to use a Remote Desktop Connection to server B and then copy to Server C.

There are other alternative methods, such as using telnet, ssh, scripts, and 3rd party programs that allow you to bypass the middleman.

Comment: This is exactly what I do and why I do it that way.

Comment: If using command line on linux, one can ssh into B, then use scp to copy from B to C.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is yes, the files are going via your desktop when transferring between 2 remote machines using explorer. You can always remote to one of the servers and move them directly from one to the other.

Answer (score 2):

If both have FTP servers running, you can skip your desktop from the route using Flash FXP. It does exactly that. IF not enabled by default, it takes 2 clicks to enable the FXP mode on most FTP servers.

FTP is designed to take care of file transfers (File Transfert Protocol). Much more reliable & efficient than native OS copy / move.