# Forcing direct transfer within a NAS using Windows Explorer on a terminal (without the use of the NAS's proprietary web app)

Tags: windows-explorer, nas, smb

Using Windows Explorer on a local PC running Windows10 (`MyPC`), if I drag and drop the example file (file1.ext, 1GB) from:

```
\\Network-NAS\FolderA\
```

to

```
\\Network-NAS\FolderB\
```

`file1.ext` seems to first transfer from `FolderA` to `MyPC`, then from `MyPC` to `FolderA`. This is less problematic for single small files than let's say 1GB files. Is there anyway to mitigate this?

For example, most NAS's uses a form of LinuxOS. There are some that come with Windows Storage Server WSS 2016 (ex: Buffalo WS5020 and some Thecus). They all come with web interfaces, however on a Windows10 PC, using Windows Explorer is much more convenient for network users. Would WSS offer any advantage with enabling a direct reference change or same disk partition to partition transfer for a large file, rather than require its usual routing of the transferred files through `MyPC` as I've experienced on simpler NAS's (for example WD-WesterDigitals)?

Update: Would iSCSI prevent sending files through the client?

Comment: possible duplicate https://superuser.com/questions/629520/moving-files-from-one-network-folder-to-another-does-the-data-come-through-my-l

Comment: Thanks for the link David - Specifically, Tonny's answer suggests that it may be possible to bypass `MyPC` in some Windows servers and I would like to configure that option in this server or know where there may be a reference to it elsewhere.

Comment: Tonny also mentioned that he never saw it used anywhere. I have a feeling that it's going to be quite difficult to find related documents. Good luck.

Comment: You could have said that from the getgo. I thought comments were meant to be helpful rather than just pure criticism of the question.

Comment: Correct me, but I thought the point of using this site was to get help rather than a user saying, 'good luck' go search on your own - unless I am missing something here? In any case, I don't think you're comments had the intention to be helpful at all, so maybe keep that in mind.

Comment: Actually I said that very sincerely. I didn't mean any criticism or sarcasm at all. I thought this was a very good question, that's why I upvoted it. I was simply trying to offer more information, which is the answer in the other Q mentioned he never saw such mechnism implemented. I myself have never seen this either, so just expressing that it might be difficult to do.